# Codeigniter View Undefined Variable Error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a program that used to manage items in a store. Everything is working fine. Then I need to get a report referred to `update_stock_id` for issued items.

Tried the following code

## Controller

```
class Reports extends FZ_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->load->model('Report_model');

    }
public function printIssuedItems($id)
    {
        $data['issuedDetail'] = $this->Report_model->printIssuedItemData($id);
        $this->load->view('reports/printIssuedItems', $data);
    }
}
```

## Model

```
function printIssuedItemData($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('store_update_stock.request_no, store_update_stock.billed_date, tbl_user.username,store_item.item_name,
        sum(store_update_stock_details.r_qty) as r_qty, sum(store_update_stock_details.ap_qty) as ap_qty,
        sum(store_update_stock_details.is_qty) as is_qty');
        $this->db->from('store_update_stock');
        $this->db->join('store_update_stock_details', 'store_update_stock.update_stock_id=store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_user', 'store_update_stock.supplier=tbl_user.userId');
        $this->db->join('store_item', 'store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id', 'right');
        $this->db->where(array('store_update_stock.update_stock_id' => $id, 'store_update_stock_details.status' => 1));
        $this->db->group_by('store_update_stock_details.item');

        $q = $this->db->get();
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        }
        return false;


    }
```

## View (Relevant part of)

```
<?php
if (!empty($issuedDetail)) {
    $issuedData = $issuedDetail[0];
}
?>

<div class="col-xs-12">
            <h2 class="page-header">

                <small class="text-center"> Request No: <b><?=$issuedData->request_no?></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Request Date: <b><?=$issuedData->billed_date?></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Officer Name: <b><?=$issuedData->username?></b></small>
            </h2>
     </div>
```

The model outs the correct result set. But executing the view, the following error message displays.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined variable: issuedData
>   Filename: reports/printIssuedItems.php
>   Line Number: 52

Backtrace:

> File:
>  C:\xampp\htdocs\wpsstores\application\views\reports\printIssuedItems.php
>   Line: 52
>   Function: _error_handler

This refers to the variable `$issuedData`.

I have checked every part of the code. But didn't identify any issue.

Comment: what shows print_r($issuedDetail)?

Comment: @ Vickel. Where to add print_r($issuedDetail)

Comment: this is a method to debug, use `print_r($data['issuedDetail']));die;` in your controller and see what the array output is (it will stop the script there!), then you can check if the array has any values and how it is structured, with that you can then "feed" your view. Here you have already !empty check, but it doesn't do any exemption, if array is empty...

Comment: @  Vickel. If used, print_r($data['issuedDetail']));die; in my controller, doesn't out anything.

Comment: because it is empty, you need to debug your `$this->Report_model->printIssuedItemData($id);`I suppose $id is undefined

Comment: @ Vickel. But $id is defined in the model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201896/discussion-between-vickel-and-mcode).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to avoid the undefined variable error in your view, you need to exclude your html code from being executed, in case the database query doesn't return any results.

change:

```
<?php
if (!empty($issuedDetail)) {
    $issuedData = $issuedDetail[0];
}
?>
YOUR HTML CODE
```

to:

```
<?php
if (!empty($issuedDetail)):
    $issuedData = $issuedDetail[0];
?>
YOUR HTML CODE
<?php else:?>no records found
<?php endif?>
```

this will show html code if query returns records, otherwise "no recs" message